# PHP time() produces wrong result on server

Tags: php, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm having a very very strange problem. Check this code snippet:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo floor(time() / 30);
```

This should produce a new result every 30 seconds. This works fine on localhost but when I upload it to my server and refresh both at the same time they both give different results:

Localhost: 47150054
Server: 47150058

Both should be the same, because i'm using this for Google Authenticator codes. I can generate correct codes on localhost but not on the server.

I used `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` but this should not matter since we are talking about Unix timestamps.

Any help on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably one of your machine's time isn't set correctly. You might want to synchronize your time with a remote server.

Comment: This was the case. Time was off by 79 seconds.